# Best practice of multiple dockized dev envionrment

Tags: docker, development-environment

Not sure, if that is a correct place to ask it or even if that is a right minded question

What is the best practice to use multiple development projects for docker as follows (using windows 10 docker desktop):

- each project contains multiple containers- reversed proxy, db-container, php || nodejs containers;
- don't want to use docker-compose down|up each time to lose DB data/seeds (not all projects can seed db or even remember last db updates - like settings of fields);
- sometimes it's necessary to run them in the same time for easier switch between projects;
- not all docker-compose.yml and dockerfile (for build) files can be changed;

Is there easy "fix" for all that?

Comment: If each project is in a directory with a different name, and you don't fix the `container_name:`, and the `ports:` conflict, you should be able to run the various projects concurrently.  Is there a specific problem you're running into?

Comment: Yeah, mostly the problem that I can connect to only one nginx-proxy. other is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use ubuntu multipass and install docker on each multipass VM? That would give you X "external" IP addresses- each IP for one of your compose projects.

```
    multipass list
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
primary                 Running           172.21.121.20    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
lenient-dingo           Running           172.21.120.211   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

It would be like:

```
multipass launch
multipass shell <instance>
```

> Install docker > run your compose file.

You can also mount one of your Windows folder to each system.

Jens